# Wrap div into parent block (no float:left)

Tags: html, css

I have parent block (graphic) and children (from 10 to around 40). I use display:block for childs and parent, but blocks goes out parent div. Float:left isn't solution.

Blocks order in parent:

```
Float left
1 2
3 4
5 6
6 7
But i need:
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

Screnshots:
[Without float:left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGlQh.png)

[image]

[Float:left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH4aC.png)

[image]

So, i need: if children goes out parent, this child and follow goes to new line.

Comment: you should add width 100% for children

Comment: can you add your code plz

Comment: @Ranjithv nope, not working.

Comment: can you please share your code..i will check and let you know

Comment: @godfather i use LESS, so in JSFiddle all gonna be broken. 
https://jsfiddle.net/zgc3ow52/

Comment: can you pls add .block_gr{width:50%;}

Comment: @Ranjithv width:50% gives zero result too.

Comment: want kind of result you need.. all childern single line or double line?

Comment: @Ranjithv I just updated my code, pass throught LESS to CSS converter. https://jsfiddle.net/zgc3ow52/1/

Comment: yes already i did.. but you want all chldern single line or double line?

Comment: @Ranjithv double line.

Answer (score 0):

can you please add this code in your LESS file

**LESS**

```
div.gen
{
  .title
  {
    *
    {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left:10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size:36px;
      vertical-align:top;
    }
    span
    {
      margin-left:-10px;
      margin-right:10px;
    }
    select
    {
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin-top:5px;
      font-size:24px;
    }
  }
}
div.graphic
{
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 950px;
  background-color:rgba(55,55,55,.5);
  display: block;
  .block_gr
  {
    width:50%;
    height:32px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
  }
  .punkt
  {
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
  }
  .times
  {
    margin-right:30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 205px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    .time
    {
      overflow:hidden;
      word-wrap:normal;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 50px;
      overflow:hidden;
      height: 28px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      position:relative;
      line-height: 28px;
      margin-right:-5px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i can't understand zero result means? @Михаил Зубов

Comment: it's giving just zero difference. 
i don't pretty much understood your message about link. you can't open link?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with flexbox

```
div.graphic
{
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 950px;
  background-color:rgba(55,55,55,.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```